# How to resolve promiss.all() and want to remove a level of object

Tags: node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

I want to merge the result of two sequelize data. So I just created instances of two models and then resolve them by using promise.All() at once. I did the following to achieve the same:

```
let screensP = AppEvent.findAll({
        attributes : [
            'id',
            'title'
        ],
    });
let eventsP = AppScreen.findAll({
        attributes : [
            'id',
            'title'
        ],
    });
exports.settings = function(req, res, next){
    Promise.all([{'screens' : screensP, 'events' : eventsP}])
    .then((values) => {
        res.json({
            'status': 200,
            'data': values,
        });
    });
}
```

But the response includes the promise object like below

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "data": [
        {
            "screens": {
                "isFulfilled": true,
                "isRejected": false,
                "fulfillmentValue": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "title": "click"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "title": "comment"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "events": {
                "isFulfilled": true,
                "isRejected": false,
                "fulfillmentValue": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the result something like this

```
{
    "status": 200,
    
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "dashboard"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "profile"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "book"
        }
    ],
    
    "screens": []
}
```

What should I do to get the above response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the call to `Promise.all()` you are passing in an array that contains one element that is an object with two properties, each of them a promise. which is what you are seeing in your results (the `isFulfilled` and other properties). To resolve the promises you need to pass in a array of promises, not an object.

This example uses `async/await` which is easier to read.

```js
exports.settings = async function(req, res) {
  // you can deconstruct the returned elements when the promise is resolved
  const [ screens, events ] = await Promise.all([
    // returns a promise that will resolve "events"
    AppEvent.findAll({
      attributes : [
          'id',
          'title'
      ],
      // if you don't need to parse to Instance objects, adding raw:true will be faster
      // raw: true,
    }),
    // returns a promise that will resolve "screens"
    AppScreen.findAll({
      attributes : [
          'id',
          'title'
      ],
      // if you don't need to parse to Instance objects, adding raw:true will be faster
    })
  ]);

  // return the results
  return res.json({
    'status': 200,
    'data': {
      screens,
      events
    },
  });
};
```

The same example using thenables:

```js
exports.settings = function(req, res) {
  // you can deconstruct the returned elements when the promise is resolved
  return Promise.all([
    // returns a promise that will resolve "events"
    AppEvent.findAll({
      attributes : [
          'id',
          'title'
      ],
    }),
    // returns a promise that will resolve "screens"
    AppScreen.findAll({
      attributes : [
          'id',
          'title'
      ],
    })
  ])
  .then(([ screens, events ]) => {
    // return the results
    return res.json({
      'status': 200,
      'data': {
        screens,
        events
      },
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks @doulesharp but can I add the identifiers like screens and events in the json response like ` "events": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "dashboard"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "profile"
        },`
 ],
    
    "screens": []

Comment: That is what my example does. When you just pass in a variable to an object it uses the variable name as the key and the variable value as the value. So... `const foo = "bar"; const obj = { foo };` would generate an object like `{ foo: "bar" }`

Comment: Sorry but doesn't seem to be generating the object like { foo : "bar"} but I'm getting result like this `"data":[{"id":1,"title":"click"},{"id":2,"title":"comment"}]`

Comment: Oh god thanks buddy I was just messed up with my code as another method was overriding the same named method

Answer (score -1):

```
    res.json({
        'status': 200,
        ...values,
    });
```

Comment: This is not correct, the promises aren't being resolved because they are being passed into Promise.all as properties of an object.